# How to see which lambda execution role is used to execute a lambda function & Diff between AssumeRole vs LambdaExecution Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

1, How can I see 'which role' is being used to execute a lambda function? I have logged event in Cloudwatch but there is nothing regarding IAM role or AssumeRole.

2, Is AssumeRole is much different from a lambda execution role? Right now in my lambda, I have a function with an authorizer. The authorizer will check the token of the user and in the call back it will pass generated policy.

So what I have understood is, 
First, we call the "Function" and Automatically it will trigger authorizer. The authorizer will pass an IAM role to the "Function" then it will execute it. So my question is, is this AssumeRole is a lambda:Execute role?

So what's the difference between the Default lambda execution role and this AssumeRole?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use AWS CloudTrail for this. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/logging-using-cloudtrail.html
2. Assumed role is the role the request acts upon. The concept of role is the most core in the AWS, to perform an action (like an API call) you have to have a role.

The authorizer uses AssumeRole to assume a role to the client. AssumeRole generates temporal IAM credential an entity can access AWS resources with. On the other hand, an execution role is the role a resource (like AWS Lambda) acts upon. For example, if your Lambda reads from a DynamoDB table, its execution role must include a permission `dynamodb:GetItem` - this doesn't have to be included in the assumed role.